# Excel - Merging two =COUNTIF functions into one cell with a standard formatting character between

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2013

Merging two =COUNTIF functions into one cell with a standard formatting character between each.

I have two functions that i want to display the data in one cell with a slash "/" between the data. How do i merge these and add a "/" symbol within 1 cell?

```
=COUNTIF(J5:J52,">0")

=COUNTIF(C5:C52,"*")
```

So for example one cell will show **"20/42"**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few ways to accomplish this with the same effect:

Using **CONCATENATE([text1],[text2])**

```
=CONCATENATE(COUNTIF(J5:J52,">0"),"/",COUNTIF(C5:C52,"*"))
```

Using "**&**"

```
=COUNTIF(J5:J52,">0")&"/"&COUNTIF(C5:C52,"*")
```